# How to add a toggle checkbox beside gameobject field?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add toggle checkboxes near each objectfield on the objectfield side beside it on the right side and not above it.

```
public void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(10);
        childrenPrefix = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Rename prefix", childrenPrefix);
        startIndex = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Start index", startIndex);
        includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);

        if (objects.Length == 0)
        {
            showPosition = false;
        }
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(true, 16f, EditorStyles.foldout);
        Rect foldRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
        if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp && foldRect.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
        {
            showPosition = !showPosition;
            GUI.changed = true;
            Event.current.Use();
        }

        showPosition = EditorGUI.Foldout(foldRect, showPosition, "Objects");
        GUILayout.Space(2);

        if (showPosition)
        {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

            scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 50;
                
                includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);
                GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.MaxWidth(100.0f), GUILayout.MinWidth(300.0f) };
                objects[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(), objects[i], typeof(GameObject), true,options);
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

            EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }
```

When i'm adding this toggle line before ObjectField it's adding the toggle above it and i want the toggle to be near it on the right side of the objectfield field.

```
includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);
```

I tried this :

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                {
                    GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.MaxWidth(100.0f), GUILayout.MinWidth(300.0f) };
                    objects[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(), objects[i], typeof(GameObject), true, options);
                    includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

but you don't see the whole toggle string name Include Children but only Includ like this :

[image: see only Includ and not Include Children near the toggle]

I tried to add the options to the toggle but it didn't change much :

```
includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren, options);
```

I tried to switch the options max width to 700 and min width to 300 and the result is : horizontal scrollbar :

[image: new horizontal scrollbar added]

Answer (score 0):

You need to place it in a horizontal area.

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
{
    includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren);
    GUILayoutOption[] options = { GUILayout.MaxWidth(100.0f), GUILayout.MinWidth(300.0f) };
    objects[i] = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(i.ToString(), objects[i], typeof(GameObject), true,options);
}
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Placing the toggle control line before your object field will result in the toggle being on the left.

Placing the toggle control after the object field will result in the toggle on the right.

Comment: I added the line includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren); after the ObjectField because i wanted the toggle to be on the right side.  now it's working but the problem now is that the name "Include Children" you see only Includ(and the toggle checkbox) you don't see the whole Include Children name of the toggle.  how to change the toggle size so the whole string name of it will be show ? I tried to make ,options but it didn't fix it : includeChildren = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", includeChildren, options);

Comment: I edited my question with your solution and what is the problem now.

Comment: You can reduce the size of the object field (changing the width layout option), or increase the window width.  Looks like your layout options are reversed, Max should be the larger number and Min should be the smaller number.  Currently it says "dont go above 100, but be at least 300"

Comment: I tried to switch it the max i set it to 700 and the min to 300 and then added the options also to the toggle but then instead making the toggle width wider it's adding a horizontal scrollbar. i will edit my question once again with what i did and what i get.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to add EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth line before the toggle line :

```
EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 112;
include1 = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Include Children", include1, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
```

Result :

[image: toggles]